# AVPlayer not working on iPad when device auto-locked

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, streaming, avplayer

I have an iOS app that plays music through streaming, it works great in iPhone. But I have a problem in iPad.
My problem is, when I play a song, after screen is auto-lock current song is playing but the next song is not played. If I lock the device manually next song is played correctly.
I log when audioPlayerDidStartPlaying delegate is executed, so I know that it is executed, but I can't heard nothing.
I got this from iPad's log.

```
Oct 31 13:48:41  mediaserverd[1891] <Notice>: 13:48:41.634 NOTE:      [0x4150000] <aqme> MEMixerChannel.cpp:777: EnableProcessor: EQ not supported for 2e+04 Hz
Oct 31 13:48:44  mediaserverd[1891] <Notice>: 13:48:44.331 NOTE:      [0x4150000] <aqme> MEMixerChannel.cpp:777: EnableProcessor: EQ not supported for 2e+04 Hz
Oct 31 13:48:44  mediaserverd[1891] <Warning>: 13:48:44.334 [0x4150000] TranslateCMSessionErrorCode: AudioSessionSetClientPlayState: WARNING translating CMSession error: -16980
Oct 31 13:48:44  mediaserverd[1891] <Error>: 13:48:44.335 ERROR:     [0x4150000] AQServer.cpp:150: SetSessionPlayState: AudioQueue: Error '!pla' from AudioSessionSetClientPlayState(0x76358a)
```

I have in my app delegate:

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:NULL];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];

// Change the default output audio route
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                            sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

And I have defined the "Required background modes" property in my info.plist file to "App plays audio".

In iPhone is working properly, so any ideas where is my problem?

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 1):

try registering for remote control events...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Although it doesn't seem to have anything to do with it, the AVPlayer and other players status seems to fail when played if your app doesn't acquire the remote controls.

In your app delegate, respond to the remote control by something like this:

```
-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    switch(event.subtype)
    {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            [self pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            [self play];
            break;

    }
}
```